# Can't get two equations to align using eqnarray

Tags: spacing, equations, arrays

I'm trying to align two equations using `eqnarray`.

Sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{\begin{center}Variance equations\end{center}}
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu = \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum\limits_{x=1}^N\sum\limits_{y=1}^MA(y,x)\nonumber\\
varTot = \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum\limits_{x=1}^N\sum\limits_{y=1}^M(A(y,x)-\mu)^2
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

The task description specifically states that I should use `eqnarray`.

Image of what it should look like (I achieved this earlier by using two `equation` environments):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If using eqnarray` you need `&=&`  but really it is better not to use that and use `align` from amsmath. Also don't use math italic for multi-letter identifiers, use `\mathit{varTot}` so it looks like a word not a product of variables, and `\begin{center` in a section title is so wrong:-) just use plain text and specify section formatting elsewhere (apart from looking weird, it will mess up the table of contents)

Comment: you don't need `\limits` (limits layout is automatic in display math for `\sum`)

Comment: Thanks for the tips mate! Adding &=& got it working. I don't understand what you mean by 'use \mathit{varTot}' I see no difference.

Comment: Make a zoom and you'll see differences: small spaces are added between letters if you don't use `\mathit`; they correspond to the side bearings, that are necessary e.g. in case of exponents or indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions, first with `eqnarray`, then with `align` (an environment provided by the `amsmath` package). Note the absurdly large amount of space around the `=` symbols when using `eqnarray` -- it's one of the reasons why `eqnarray` is considered badly deprecated these days and really shouldn't be used anymore.

Incidentally, since both `eqnarray` and `align` set their material in `\displaystyle` math mode, `\limits` is on by default and needn't be specified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{With \ttfamily eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu &=& \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum_{x=1}^N\sum_{y=1}^MA(y,x)\nonumber\\
\mathrm{varTot} &=& \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum_{x=1}^N\sum_{y=1}^M(A(y,x)-\mu)^2
\end{eqnarray}

\subsubsection*{With \ttfamily align}
\begin{align}
\mu &= \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum_{x=1}^N\sum_{y=1}^MA(y,x)\nonumber\\
\mathrm{varTot} &= \tfrac{1}{NM}\sum_{x=1}^N\sum_{y=1}^M(A(y,x)-\mu)^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```